# Keycloak SSO Pentaho integration

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, pentaho, keycloak

i'm pretty new with Pentaho.
This is my use case:
I use SSO Jboss Keycloak as my single sign on server. I have already developed few applications which already use it, now this is the time to wrap Pentaho BI inside the SSO mechanism.

I have read Pentaho authentication is based on Spring Security and luckily Keycloak offers a Spring Security Adapter by which i can secure a spring application with keycloak authentication.
Can someone help me by listing some steps i have to do in order to develop an authentication keycloak provider to be integrated inside pentaho authentication process?
I mean that:
- when i try to login pentaho web application i will be redirected to keycloak SSO login form.
- when i try to access pentaho web applications, being already authenticated by other applications, i can do it without any credential request.

Coming more into detail, i have successfully tried to develop a spring secured application using keycloak SSO.
It could simply done by modifying the security-context.xml as the following listing:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity" />

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="keycloakAuthenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>


    <bean id="adapterDeploymentContextBean" class="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.AdapterDeploymentContextBean" >
        <constructor-arg value="/WEB-INF/keycloak.json" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="keycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <bean id="keycloakAuthenticationProvider" class="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationProvider" />
    <bean id="keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter" class="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter" />
    <bean id="keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter" class="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
        <constructor-arg name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="keycloakLogoutHandler" class="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakLogoutHandler">
        <constructor-arg ref="adapterDeploymentContextBean" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="logoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
        <constructor-arg name="logoutSuccessUrl" value="/" />
        <constructor-arg name="handlers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="keycloakLogoutHandler" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="logoutRequestMatcher">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher">
                <constructor-arg name="pattern" value="/sso/logout**" />
                <constructor-arg name="httpMethod" value="GET" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <security:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="keycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
        <security:custom-filter ref="keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter" before="LOGOUT_FILTER" />
         <security:custom-filter ref="keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
         <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasRole('MYROLE')" />
         <security:custom-filter ref="logoutFilter" position="LOGOUT_FILTER" />
    </security:http>
</beans>
```

So i m wondering if this mechanism could be easily imported into petaho application-security-context.xml

Thanks a lot